# How to make a simple histogram with WinForms chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, histogram

I would like to create a simple histogram, like that one: [CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNTMa.png). With my code it looks totally different: [CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7T55.png). My problems are:

- redundant YAxis label
- the numbers are displayed too often (I would like to have maximum of 5-6 per axis)
- the chequered pattern behind chart is too dense
- the bars are not distributed regularly (there are some white spaces, black lines)

What should I change to achieve a nice histogram?

My code:

```
ChartR.Legends.Clear();
ChartR.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 5;
ChartR.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 5;
ChartR.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;

var dataPointSeries = new Series
{
    Name = "Series 1",
    Color = Color.Red,
    IsVisibleInLegend = true,
    ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
};

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    dataPointSeries.Points.AddXY(i, i);
}

ChartR.Series.Add(dataPointSeries);
```

Comment: Play with these properties for both Axes: Interval, MajorGridlineXXX and to avoid a Moiree effect make the columns (not Bars, btw) thinner (CustomProperty["PixelPointWidth"]) or the chart larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @TaW, that helped! I made a histogram like that:

```
ChartR.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
ChartR.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
ChartR.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 50;
ChartR.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 20;
ChartR.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;

var dataPointSeries = new Series
{
    Name = "Series 1",
    Color = Color.Red,
    ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
};

for (int i = 2; i < 255; i++)
{
    dataPointSeries.Points.AddXY(i, i);
}

ChartR.Series.Add(dataPointSeries);
ChartR.Series["Series 1"]["PixelPointWidth"] = "1";
```